# Data appended to table is added to one column instead of all four

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

This is a simplified Bootstrap table created in JavaScript for a shopping cart. I have one row with four columns. The problem is when I open it in Chrome all the data for columns 2, 3 and 4 are all placed in column 1.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" id="productsList">
    </div>

    <script>
            var productsList = document.getElementById('productsList');
            productsList.innerHTML += '<table class="table table-striped">' +
                                          '<thead>' +
                                              '<tr>' +
                                              '<th>Shopping cart</th>' +
                                              '<th>Name</th>' +
                                              '<th>Price</th>' +
                                              '<th>Quantity</th>' +
                                              '</tr>' +
                                          '</thead>' +
                                          '<tbody>';


            productsList.innerHTML += '<tr>' +
                                              '<td><div><img style="width:200px; height:300px;" src="nopicture.jpg" /></div></td>' +
                                              '<td>' +
                                                  '<h6 id="productname"> Nice Product</h6>' +
                                                  '<a href="#" onclick="deleteProduct(\'' + name + '\')" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</a>' +
                                              '</td>' +
                                              '<td><div id="productprice">Tshs. 5000/=</div></td>' +
                                              '<td><div id="productquantity">3</div></td>' +
                                          '</tr>';




            productsList.innerHTML +=  '</tbody>' +
                                          '</table>';

    </script>
</body>
```

```
function fetchProducts() {
var products = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('products'));
var productsList = document.getElementById('productsList');

productsList.innerHTML += '<table class="table table-striped">' +
                              '<thead>' +
                                  '<tr>' +
                                  '<th>Shopping cart</th>' +
                                  '<th>Name</th>' +
                                  '<th>Price</th>' +
                                  '<th>Quantity</th>' +
                                  '</tr>' +
                              '</thead>' +
                              '<tbody>';
for(var i in products) {
    var picture = products[i].picture;
    var name = products[i].name;
    var price = products[i].price;
    var quantity = products[i].quantity;

    productsList.innerHTML += '<tr>' +
                                  '<td><div id="productpicture"><img src=\'' + picture + '\' /></div></td>' +
                                  '<td>' +
                                      '<h6 id="productname">' + name + '</h6>' +
                                      '<a href="#" onclick="deleteProduct(\'' + name + '\')" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</a>' +
                                  '</td>' +
                                  '<td><div id="productprice">Tshs.' + price + '/=</div></td>' +
                                  '<td><div id="productquantity">' + quantity + '</div></td>' +
                              '</tr>';

}


   productsList.innerHTML +=  '</tbody>' +
                              '</table>';

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't append to the `innerHTML` of an element like that.  When you do it the first time, Chrome tries to close out your table for you and make it valid HTML.  The second+ time you are appending HTML after your table is closed with `</table>`.  Put the HTML into a local variable instead and then assign `innerHTML` once at the end.

```
function fetchProducts() {
    var products = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('products'));
    var productsList = document.getElementById('productsList');

    var content = '<table class="table table-striped">' +
                                  '<thead>' +
                                      '<tr>' +
                                      '<th>Shopping cart</th>' +
                                      '<th>Name</th>' +
                                      '<th>Price</th>' +
                                      '<th>Quantity</th>' +
                                      '</tr>' +
                                  '</thead>' +
                                  '<tbody>';
    for (var i in products) {
        var picture = products[i].picture;
        var name = products[i].name;
        var price = products[i].price;
        var quantity = products[i].quantity;

        content += '<tr>' +
                                      '<td><div id="productpicture"><img src=\'' + picture + '\' /></div></td>' +
                                      '<td>' +
                                          '<h6 id="productname">' + name + '</h6>' +
                                          '<a href="#" onclick="deleteProduct(\'' + name + '\')" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</a>' +
                                      '</td>' +
                                      '<td><div id="productprice">Tshs.' + price + '/=</div></td>' +
                                      '<td><div id="productquantity">' + quantity + '</div></td>' +
                                  '</tr>';

    }


    content += '</tbody>' + '</table>';
    productsList.innerHTML = content;
}
```

Comment: @aaronw The problems I have to Enter data dynamically, there is a for loop which add data dynamically in that middle part `productsList.innerHTML`, thats why I separated them. I need to add `tr` dynamically

Comment: That changes nothing. There's no reason you can't append to a local variable instead of `productsList.innerHTML` inside a loop.

Comment: Just do what @PaulAbbott said, [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/r809ajLv/2/) is an updated fiddle.

Comment: I have added a function the real one am using.

Comment: @PaulAbbott I am kind of new to javascript I didn't understood you well, but thats my function

Comment: Can you assist me some tips from here

Comment: @Developer [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is the stack exchange site to ask about improving working code. My very quick tip is to end `img` tags with `>` instead of `/>` -  there is not end image tag.